# How to install *.vba.gz to Vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am installing [DrawIt](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=40) to Vim. The instructions are

```
vim DrawIt.vba.gz 
:so % 
:q
```

I first checked whether [vimballPlugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1502) is present, and it is:

```
:scriptnames
  1: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

This is what I saw after `vim DrawIt.vba.gz`:

[image]

and after `so %`:

[image]

Am I missing anything? Thank you.

**Update**:

If I `vim DrawIt.vba` then `so %`, the error will be

```
Error detected while processing ~/DrawIt.vba:
line    2:
E492: Not an editor command: UseVimball
```

**Update2**:

The issue was from some misconfiguration of Cygwin, which made Vim fail to find `~/.vim`

Comment: Both screenshots are quite pretty, actually.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ZIP plugin didn't properly unzip the file. It's probably easiest to do that separately (e.g. with WinZip), and then just work on the expanded Vimball:

```
vim DrawIt.vba
:so %
:q
```

Alternatively, you can use the plugin's [vimscripts.org mirror](https://github.com/vim-scripts/DrawIt) to download a ZIP (without Vimball), or use the GitHub repository with plugin managers like *Pathogen*, *Vundle*, etc.

Comment: Doesn't work either. I've updated the question and added the error message.

Comment: Something in your Vim configuration is wrong, that's why (even though they are sourced), the Zip plugin doesn't work, and the `:UseVimball` command isn't available. Do you have `:set compatible?`, that prevents the plugins from functioning.

Comment: I figured it out. I set another home folder for Cygwin but there was some inconsistency. Now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing myself attempting to install Align.vba.gz for GVim 8.2 on Windows 10 Pro.  This worked for me and hope it helps others.

Download the plugin you are interested in.  Navigate to the directory containing the downloaded file.

From Windows explorer, I right-clicked on Align.vba.gz, selected 7-Zip then Extract to "Align.vba".

The file extracted in the download directory.

Now, the instructions work.

gvim Align.vba
:so %
:q

Everything then happens as it should.  There seems to be a presumption installers know to extract the Align.vba.gz file.  The rest of the plugin instructions will need to be followed for the particular plugin being utilized.